# Python.exe не видит файлы

Tags: python, парсер, excel

Написал прогу для работы с файлами, собрал в .exe с помощью pyinstaller, попытался запустить итоговую программу, и вот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сам парсер на вход принимает на вход excel файл, и у меня подозрение, что именно какая-то библиотека не архивируется в exe.

Comment: прогресс 4/25 это чем вывели ?

Comment: `sys.stdout.write('\r')` такая команда стирает напечатанное на преведущей строке в терминале

Comment: А про не найден файл это ваш текст программа печатает? Надо смотреть, что там в exception валится, если это исключение. Так только гадать

Comment: Вангую проблемы с кодировками

Comment: Python - регистрозависимый язык. Возможно, ему не понравилось d: в пути к исходному файлу?

Comment: а нихера, pyinstaller создаёт exe, который делает вагон временных файлов `C:\Users\edvar\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI79562`

Answer (score 1):

Крч начал я ошибки разгребать, оказалось что в open-source библиотеке с user-agent был какой-то файл, который не архивировался. Код отлавливал FileNotFindError, но из-за ненахождения совершенно другого файла.

Проверяйте библиотеки с open-source вообщем